# Firebase 404 css breaks if requested from a folder inside public

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I have the following project tree in `/public`

[image: /public].

On my website, if I request a non-existent page from a page in `/public`, e.g. `mydomain.com/nonexistentpage`, it throws a 404 page properly.

However, if I request a non-existent page from `mydomain.com/folder/nonexistentpage`, it breaks everything except HTML. Errors thrown in the browser indicate that it's looking for assets in `/public/folder/files` and `/public/folder`, while the actual files are in `/public/files` and `/public`.

My `firebase.json` is:

```json
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "cleanUrls": true,
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  }
}
```

What do I do to make the 404 page appear properly on any page?

Comment: Yes, the path is correct as all other pages appear properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if you don't use relative paths when using `<link>`.